# What does "Not a direct connection" mean in AnyDesk?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote, remote-control, anydesk

I'm using AnyDesk to do some work on a remote computer and this work requires me to view fast-moving objects and animations in high quality. So I've set my "Work mode" to "Video" and my "Quality" to "Best":

[image: AnyDesk Settings]

This works for the most part but is still pretty laggy. I see a message or error as well on that screenshot above that says:

> Not a direct connection: Transmission might be affected.

Both computers are connected via Ethernet. The host computer (Windows 10) is running a 1Gbps fibre connection and the client computer (Windows 11) is running a 150Mbps 5G Mobile Internet connection. Both computers are also running AnyDesk version 8.0.6

What does "Not a direct connection" mean? Is it because the two computers aren't on the same network? I'm assuming this "Not a direct connection" message is the reason why it's laggy, but I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From AnyDesk [Settings](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/settings) :

> **Direct Connection**
>
> If direct connections are enabled in "Settings" > Connection >
> "General", AnyDesk will try to create a session tunnel between this
> AnyDesk client and the client it is trying to connect to.
>
> If disabled, the AnyDesk session between the local and remote
> endpoints are routed through our servers. Please note that as AnyDesk
> sessions are encrypted, AnyDesk cannot and will not look into your
> session data.
>
> In general, direct connections are usually faster than a routed
> connection. However, for some network environments, you may experience
> network instability due to firewall or other security solution
> settings. Disable direct connections in the settings to avoid
> unexpected session ends.

This is apparently a warning that you have either
disabled direct connections in "Settings > Connection > General",
or the creation of a session tunnel between this
AnyDesk client and the client it is trying to connect
to have failed.

The warning means that the AnyDesk session between the local
and remote endpoints are now routed through the AnyDesk servers.
The article notes that AnyDesk sessions are encrypted and the
AnyDesk server cannot and will not look into your session data.

Answer (score 0):

> What does "Not a direct connection" mean? Is it because the two computers aren't on the same network?

Not quite. In a sense they are on the same network – *the Internet* – but they're unable to talk to each other *through* the Internet, most likely because both of them are behind NAT gateways and/or firewalls, which causes difficulties with regular inbound connections (often needing manual "port forwarding" configuration), and the usual ["NAT traversal"](https://tailscale.com/blog/how-nat-traversal-works) trickery that AnyDesk should've had didn't succeed in establishing the connection either.

(The 5G connection is likely behind *two* layers of NAT – your home router/modem plus the network operator's system – as it's probably on the same infrastructure as regular mobile customers, where most network operators use CGNAT extensively… but these days there's no guarantee that the fiber connection isn't behind CGNAT, either. All of that makes it extremely annoying to establish a direct host-to-host connection.)

So what's happening instead is that both computers are talking to an AnyDesk *relay* server, which might well be a significant detour (and I wouldn't be surprised if the relay servers had limits as well). For example, if both hosts have ~30 ms round-trip latency to the closest relay server, that's ~60 ms total, which will certainly feel a bit laggy.

AnyDesk has an [article](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/firewall) on their "Support" website regarding this; it suggests making sure that port 6568 is available for inbound connections (although it's not clear whether it has to be available on the target host specifically or whether it's enough to have it on either of them).

It's overall the same concept as with games, VoIP programs, or BitTorrent connections.

Answer (score 0):

The direct connect functionality has been busted for some time now with the 8.x.x releases of AnyDesk. If you downgrade the machine you need to remote into to the latest 7.x.x version of AnyDesk, you'll see that the direct connect works as expected.

The only rub with this is that AnyDesk forcibly disables you from disabling automatic upgrades without a paid subscription, so this will continually be upgraded every few days. I've found that I can leave the 7.x.x installer on the remote PC and run it while remoted in. The connection will then crash, but you can reconnect in a few seconds and you should see a direct connection established for the new connection.